# How to create include files in Lua language?

Tags: header, lua, require

I want to create a header file in Lua (header.lua), then execute the `require` function to load it.

How do I execute `require` to a file that I have created?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
require "header"
```

See the `require` entry in [the Lua Reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-require). The file "header.lua" must be somewhere in Lua's search path.

You can see (and modify) the path at

```
package.path
```

See the `package.path` entry in the [the Lua Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.path)

[This wiki page](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaModuleFunctionCritiqued) describes ways of creating modules to load with `require`.

Comment: require"header" is the correct form for the default path because require use module names not file names.

Answer (score 6):

```
require "codelibrary.variables";
```

Here `require` will look for a `variables.lua` file inside `codelibrary` directory. The `.` is a cross-platform path separator.

Answer (score 0):

## For neovim

Also the config directory can be named differently in different distos:

In my Ubuntu 20.04 it is at `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim` in other systems it might be `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/neovim`.
To the see the correct directory name, open nvim and write `:h rtp`