# Requiring a Lua file that uses a function declared in the other Lua file

Tags: lua, require

I have this issue in Lua where I have 2 files. FileA may look like this:

```
require "FileB"
local function foo(bar)
    -- random stuff
end
```

And FileB looks like this

```
foo(bar)
```

But an error pops up, saying that `foo` is an invalid function. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: That may help [How to create include files in Lua language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932172/how-to-create-include-files-in-lua-language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal practice would be to put the functions in the required file,  not the calling code.

In any case as you have your code above, you are calling foo before you are defining it.  So move the require below the definition of foo, and don't use local.

```
function foo(bar)
    -- random stuff
end

require "FileB"
```

Comment: This does not work because foo is local and cannot be seen in FileB, which is calling a global foo.